# letsrate gem wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rating

I'm using using [letsrate](https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate) gem and getting the following error:

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (3 for 2):
lib/letsrate/lib/letsrate/model.rb:69:in `letsrate_rateable'
app/models/model_definition.rb:3:in `<class:ModelDefinition>'
app/models/model_definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I've tried to downgrade version from `1.0.9` to `1.0.8` and then I've copied the source to `lib` directory still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: got it fixed? any other suggestions?

Comment: I have this error with 1.0.9 as well..

Comment: Please show the code you're using to implement the gem. The docs show it needs to be added to models, prepared, etc -- did you do all this?

Answer (score 0):

The code shown in the [master branch of the letsrate gem](https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate/blob/master/lib/letsrate/model.rb) shows that the method in question accepts a variable number of arguments.

Try installing the gem from the master branch of GitHub to correct the problem. Add this code to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`

```
gem 'letsrate', git: '/muratguzel/letsrate'
```